# How to remove a message after a specific period of time in DiscordJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have a question demanding DiscordJS.

It is, how to properly delete a Discord message that the bot sent?

I know it's a newbie question, but I'm new to DiscordJS.

I'm very thankful for all the responses I get, no matter if helpful or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the `.delete` method for the message object in order to delete the message. Just wait until the message is sent and then delete it after a certain period of time.

For **(Rich)embeds**, use the following code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const RichEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setAuthor('test');

const message = await message.channel.send({ embed: RichEmbed }).then(r => r.delete('time in milliseconds'));
```

For **normal messages**, use the following code:

```
const message = await message.channel.send('Hello').then(r => r.delete('time in milliseconds'))
```